# How to keep up to date with Facebook APIs?

Tags: facebook

Somehow I have the feeling that I am not the only one scratching my head with FB documentation. There seems to be quite a lot of overlapping features in APIs and I cannot tell whether something is going to be deprecated or not.

How can I find the *current* best practices? And any recommendations of FB technology blogs etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FB dev blog? http://developers.facebook.com/blog/ 
They are pretty up-to-date and talk about recent changes to Facebook APIs..

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

Comment: Just to add to that: the breaking change policy is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/change-policy/

Let us know what we can do better, too